# Is there an addr2line which analyzes Code in Memory?

Tags: gdb, stack-trace, backtrace, addr2line

I'm using `addr2line` to analyze the stacktrace after an exception was thrown (using backtrace and backtrace_symbols). Currently this takes about 2 seconds to analyze the 120Mb binary (debug build) from disk.

Is there a library (LGPL), which does the same job by analyzing the code segment in memory? Of course this limits me to analyze only the own application - but in my use-case this is enough.

Answer (score 3):

You want (BSD licensed) [libunwind](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/man/libunwind%283%29.html#section_2):

```
void backtrace(void)
{
    int r;
    unw_cursor_t cursor; unw_context_t uc; 
    unw_word_t ip, sp; 
    char symname[100];

    unw_getcontext(&uc);
    unw_init_local(&cursor, &uc);
    while (unw_step(&cursor) > 0) {
        r = unw_get_reg(&cursor, UNW_REG_IP, &ip);
        assert(r == 0);
        r = unw_get_reg(&cursor, UNW_REG_SP, &sp);
        assert(r == 0);
        r = unw_get_proc_name(&cursor, symname, sizeof(symname), NULL);
        assert(r == 0);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: ip: %lx, sp: %lx\n", symname, (long) ip, (long) sp);
    }   
}
```

Note that `unw_get_proc_name()` will fail (return non 0) if you strip the symbol and string tables from your binaries.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the executable recognized by the proc filesystem?
(or is it actually an executable within the memory of a process?)

```
addr2line -e /proc/32213/exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Libbacktrace, which is part of the GCC distribution does this. It handles stack unwinding, ELF symbols and debugging symbols, i.e. it provides the functionality of both libunwind and addr2line.

I have put a standalone fork here:

https://github.com/ErwanLegrand/libbacktrace